# How can net money flow be positive while stock price drops

Tags: stock-analysis

This is the price and money flow chart for a public stock on the HKEX.

I'm confused as to why the stock price kept dropping throughout the day while the net money flow by both retail and major (institutional) investors were positive and kept climbing over the same period.

Please enlighten me!

[image: 00241 Price vs Money Flow]

Answer (score 1):

The Money Flow indicator is the N period sum of positive money flow divided by the N period sum of negative money flow and therefore it may not correlate directionally with the price of the current period (up or down).  IOW, they may diverge.

In order to clearly see why the Money Flow indicator is diverging from price, you need to see the calculations.  So either find a web site that provides the calculations (unlikely) or write a spreadsheet that calculates it.  Here's one such [site](https://investexcel.net/calculate-money-flow-index-excel/).  And a word of warning - Be careful about downloading from unknown sources.